# Why my binary search using while loop dosnt work?

Tags: binary-search

I tried to write binary search code using while loop but i missed something because its not working for all inputs.

```
function solution(A, X) {
    var N = A.length;
    if (N === 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    var l = 0;
    var r = N-1;
    while (l < r) {
        var m = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);
        if (A[m] > X) {
            r = m - 1;
        } else {
            l = m;
        }
    }
    if (A[l] == X) {
        return l;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

what did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

You have made mistakes at three points:

1. While loop: It should be

   `while (l <= r)`
2. Else condition when X > A[m]:

   `l = m + 1;`
3. Finding the element. In binary search we check element present at mid point where as you are checking at A[l]. It should be

   ```
    if (A[m] == X){
     return m;
   }
   ```

And also you have written N===0. You might have made syntactical error there.